# file not rendering in django template

Tags: python, django, templates, encoding

I have some code which is supposed to render a file from svn into an email

```
command = 'svn cat -r {} "{}{}"'.format(svn_revision, svn_repo, filename)
file_content = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()

context = {
    'file_content': file_content,
}

print file_content

email = get_template('file_email/file_email.txt').render(Context(context))

print email
```

The email template is (for now) just:

```
{{file_content|safe}}
```

- The first print statement dumps the file as expected.
- The second print statement prints nothing.
- The template is rendered, if I put words around the tag then they show up.

It only happens for some files (others work fine) and it seems to be an encoding problem. Notepad++ believes the offending files are encoded "UCS-2 Little Endian" whereas the ones that work are "UTF-8 without BOM".

How can I reliably dump a file, regardless of encoding, to a template?

Comment: What Python version is this?

Comment: From what I find, UCS-2 Little Endian files are UTF-16 files. So you need to ensure all files are loaded, decoded using the proper encoding and, if needed, encoded again using UTF-8. The only way to do this correctly is to know how what files is encoded in what encoding. You can get it correct most of the time by deciding upon an encoding yourself but in general you need to know the encoding of files yourself.

Comment: Python 2.7, would 3 help?

Comment: You'd still need to know why some files are different and which ones. Otherwise you're guessing the encoding at best.

Comment: So I should install chardet, decode then recode?

Comment: If the files that you obtain by doing that are good then yes. If you know the encoding for each file then do that, otherwise use encoding detection and apply encode/decode accordingly.